# How to use the `if` options on `validatesUniquenessOf` of Loopback?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

The loopback documentation describes a validation method `validatesUniquenessOf` which has an option to add `if` property. But there are no examples provided. How do I write something like this?

I have the following context:

**The model JSON file:**

`{
    "name": "CategoryKit",
    "properties": {
        "isDeleted": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        }
    },
    "relations": {
        "category": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "Category",
            "foreignKey": "categoryId"
        },
        "kit": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "Kit",
            "foreignKey": "kitId"
        }
    },
}`

**The model javascript file:**

`module.exports = function(CategoryKit) {
    CategoryKit.validatesUniquenessOf("kitId", { scopedTo: ["categoryId"] });
}`

Now, i want that this validation working if only the `isDeleted` property is equal `false`.

Comment: Could you share your code snippet or something that you have worked on so far so we can have the context?

Comment: Hi @Sashi, I edited the post with the context. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the example on the [loopback api docs](https://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback-datasource-juggler/#validatable-validatesinclusionof)

```
 SiteUser.validateUniquenessOf('login', { scopedTo: ['siteId'] });
```

For your particular use case, can you see if this works?

```
SiteUser.validateUniquenessOf('mobile', { if: '90443123' });
```

Comment: Hi @Sashi, I edited the post with the context. Thanks!